# how to fix list index out of range in python

Tags: python, list

i have a function that append item to a list then i want to print the each using **.format()**

If i try to print the `self.checked[0]` it will print the selected item  but if it try   `self.checked[0],self.checked[1]` system crash.

the problem is when i am trying to print each item the system display this error:

```
 self.display_event_mouhafaza.setText(" {} over {}".format(self.checked[0],self.checked[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

where is the error in my code?

```
def selectionChanged(self):
        checked = []
        for row in range(self.header_list.count()):
            item = self.header_list.item(row)
            if item.checkState():
                checked.append(item)
        print("Checked items: ", ", ".join(i.text() for i in checked))
        self.checked = [i.text() for i in checked]
        self.display_event_person.setText("total of {} ".format(self.checked[0]))
        self.display_event_mouhafaza.setText(" {} over {}".format(self.checked[0],self.checked[1]))

#part that display items in the qlistWidget
        self.header_list.clear()
        savelist = list(self.df)
        for item in savelist:
            qitem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem ( ) 
            qitem.setText ( item ) 
            qitem.setCheckState ( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked ) 
            self.header_list.addItem ( qitem )
```

here the `self.checked` includes 3 items.
[image]

Comment: for whatever reason `self.checked` has only one element. print it to see what it looks like. It may help identify the problem.

Comment: Please share `header_list` value

Comment: What is the output of the "Checked items" print statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.display_event_mouhafaza.setText(" {} over {}".format(self.checked[0],self.checked[1]))
```

To get rid of index out of range , you would need a default value , let print empty space "" if index out of range

```
if len(self.checked) < 2 :
    print( 'This is your self.checked does not have second value ', self.checked)
else:
    self.display_event_mouhafaza.setText(" {} over {}".format(
             self.checked[0]
             self.checked[1]
    ))
```

Comment: in you answer it print the first item only. `self.checked[0]`

Comment: Because self.checked have only 1 item, there is no second value. Eddited

Comment: no it has 3 items i will add an image for the debug process